# Scale glBitmap() drawing?

Tags: c, opengl

I draw a character using `glBitmap()` in OpenGL.

This character is too small, so I want to draw it with a bigger size.  But when I changed size of this character I got a problem which I can't solve.

Here is a screenshot showing my problem:

[image: screen of my problem]

and here is my code:

```
GLubyte rasters[ 24 ] =
{
    0xc0, 0x00, 0xc0, 0x00, 0xc0, 0x00, 0xc0, 0x00,
    0xc0, 0x00, 0xff, 0x00, 0xff, 0x00, 0xc0, 0x00,
    0xc0, 0x00, 0xc0, 0x00, 0xff, 0xc0, 0xff, 0xc0,
};

void display()
{
    glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );
    glColor3f( 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 );
    glRasterPos2i( 80, 80 );
    glBitmap( 100, 120, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, rasters );
    glBitmap( 100, 120, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, rasters );
    glBitmap( 100, 120, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, rasters );
    glFlush();
}
```

Comment: Why are you telling OpenGL that `rasters` contains `100 * 120 = 12000` bits when it only has `24 * 8 = 192` bits?

Comment: i know that was wrong now i want to make my character bigger than this can help me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Provide enough bits in your `rasters` array to match your `glBitmap()` call's `width`/`height` arguments (i.e., pre-scale the bitmap using your favorite method), or
- Render your small bitmap to a texture using your favorite method and then render a textured quad using it, or
- Convert your bitmap to a texture and use that to draw a scaled quad directly.